# typescript parent class is calling derived function

Tags: oop, inheritance, typescript

I have got a base class and a derived one, each has init function.

When i construct the derived one i want it to:

1. call its base constructor which:

   1.1. calls its init function
2. call its own(derived) init function.

The problem is that the derived init function is called twice.

Code:

```
class Base{
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init(){
        console.log("Base init");
    }
}
class Derived extends Base{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.init();
    }
    init(){
        console.log("Derived init");
    }
}
var obj = new Derived ();
```

Output:

```
Derived init
Derived init
```

Comment: init is overwritten that's what it's all about ... In derived can you do sth like base.init() or super.init(). I do not know the typescript keyword - anyways you have to call the Base method explictly. However while theoratically interestang this would be a bad design IMHO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case, we want base `init()` to be called and then child `init()` we can solve it like this:

```
constructor() {
    super.init();
    super();        
}
```

Check the [example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22base%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%09%09super.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%7B%0A%09%09var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22Derived%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Derived%20()%3B%0A)

Solution when firstly child and then base should be like this.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    //this.init();
    super.init();
}
```

A working example is in [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22base%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%7B%0A%09%09var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22Derived%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Derived%20()%3B%0A). Click the RUN to see two buttons generated

If we want just our derived stuff to be used, we do not have to call `init` again:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    //this.init();
    // init will be called in super
}
```

This example just uses the [child stuff](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22base%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fsuper.init()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init()%7B%0A%09%09var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22Derived%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Derived%20()%3B%0A)

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, but i wanted the order to be 1.parent.init,2.derived.init.

Comment: Make sense, then just call `super.init(); super();` ;) ;). I also extended my answer and added another example...

Answer (score 5):

Another approach could be this (using also Radim's playground example) :

```
   class Base{
    constructor() {
        this.init();
    }
    init(){
        var button = document.createElement('button');      
        button.textContent = "base init";
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
}
class Derived extends Base{
    constructor() {
        super();

    }
    init(){
        super.init();
        var button = document.createElement('button');      
        button.textContent = "Derived init";
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }
}
var obj = new Derived ();
```

By calling the ancestor's init function from the derived class you can get the wanted flow.

Consider the anscestor's init a virtual method that gets overridden in the derived class(-es).

[Playground Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.init%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init%28%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement%28%27button%27%29%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22base%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild%28button%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20init%28%29%7B%0A%09%09super.init%28%29%3B%0A%09%09var%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement%28%27button%27%29%3B%09%09%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20button.textContent%20%3D%20%22Derived%20init%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild%28button%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20Derived%20%28%29%3B%0A)